# how to check the existence of a variable in the global scope?

Tags: python, python-3.x

please help to solve the problem.

```
#а = 'dg'

try:
    a
except:
    print('y')
else:
    print('n')
```

the following code should check for the existence of the variable in the global scope. as the variable "a" does not exist, then the screen should show "n". but is a "y"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you inverted `'y'` and `'n'`:

```
try:
    a
except NameError:
    print('n')
else:
    print('y')
```

If you try to use `a` without defining it, it will raise an error and print `'n'`.

Comment: never use `except:`, define at least `except Exception:`.

Comment: @Tupteq yes i was already editing my post for that, thank you anyway :)

Comment: @fede1024 `NameError` is already a built-in name, no need to import.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Edit.

Comment: with an error message understood. but all the same variable is not checked even when defined. the following code displays "n".
а = 'dg'

try:
    a
except:
    print('n')
else:
    print('y')

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you're checking in the global *and* local scope, but that's OK.

```
try:
    a
except NameError:
    print('n')
else:
    print('y')
```

Python searches for that variable in all the available namespaces, in order:

- local namespace - specific to the current function or class method. If the function defines a local variable x, or has an argument x, Python will use this and stop searching.
- global namespace - specific to the current module. If the module has defined a variable, function, or class called x, Python will use that and stop searching.
- built-in namespace - global to all modules. As a last resort, Python will assume that x is the name of built-in function or variable.

Answer (score 0):

**How about directly look into globals() namespace dictionary:**

```
 >>> n = 'print'
 >>> if 'n' in globals():
 ...     print 'n'
 ... else:
 ...     print 'y'
 ...
 n
 >>> del n
 >>> if 'n' in globals():
 ...     print 'n'
 ... else:
 ...     print 'y'
 ...
 y
 >>>
```

**For local you can check in `locals()` too:**